# Kafka vertica consumer and rejection table

Tags: apache-kafka, vertica

I see very strange behavior using vertica kafka consumer:

```
2016-07-27 04:22:17.307 com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.StreamCoordinator::Main  [INFO] Starting frame @ 2016-07-27 04:22:17.307
2016-07-27 04:22:17.330 com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.FrameScheduler::Main  [INFO] Starting compute batches for new Frame.
2016-07-27 04:22:17.431 com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.FrameScheduler::Main  [INFO] Completed computing batch set for current Frame.
2016-07-27 04:22:17.469 com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.LaneWorker::Lane Worker 2 ("openx"."requests"-CREATE@2016-07-27 04:22:17.431) [ERROR] Rolling back MB: [Vertica][VJDBC](4213) ROLLBACK: Object "requests_rej" already exists
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4213) ROLLBACK: Object "requests_rej" already exists
    at com.vertica.util.ServerErrorData.buildException(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VResultSet.fetchChunk(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VResultSet.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VQueryExecutor.readExecuteResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VQueryExecutor.handleExecuteResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VQueryExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeWithParams(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.MicroBatch.execute(MicroBatch.java:193)
    at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.LaneWorker.run(LaneWorker.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.vertica.support.exceptions.SyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4213) ROLLBACK: Object "requests_rej" already exists
    ... 11 more
2016-07-27 04:22:17.469 com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.LaneWorker::Lane Worker 2  [INFO] Lane Worker 2 waiting for batch...
2016-07-27 04:22:17.469 com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.StreamCoordinator::Main  [INFO] Sleeping for 9838 milliseconds until 2016-07-27 04:22:27.307. Started frame @ 2016-07-27 04:22:17.307.
2016-07-27 04:22:27.308 com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.StreamCoordinator::Main  [INFO] Starting frame @ 2016-07-27 04:22:27.307
2016-07-27 04:22:27.331 com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.FrameScheduler::Main  [INFO] Starting compute batches for new Frame.
2016-07-27 04:22:27.427 com.vertica.solutions.kafka.scheduler.FrameScheduler::Main  [INFO] Completed computing batch set for current Frame.
```

I do as documentation says, but on write into vertica see this error! Why I see it? How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, it seems you are using the same object for multiple create stmt, try ti use a parameter as the tbl name and see the outcome eh : table_tej$version123

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly mentions that

> Object "requests_rej" already exists

Try dropping the object and running your job.

Comment: This obvious solution, of course I did it, several times. Doesn't help! Note, that this table created automatically by kafka scheduler in vertica.